# How do I select text in-between and including two keywords in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I can select and then copy generated source (source including changes I've made locally using Javascript) code in-between and including two keywords using javascript. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- START COPYING -->
<title>Wave</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="editor.php">Edit this page >></a>
<span>Some text</span>
<!-- END COPYING -->
</body>
</html>
```

I'd want to have everything from  to  selected and copied to the clipboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you did yet? any code ?

Comment: Where is the generated code you want to select from? In a variable? In an html element?

Comment: I've worked out how to select 1 phrase, however, cannot work out how to select in between two phrases. Copying the text to the clipboard should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: are you trying to copy source code from a html/javascript response? If so did you try using document.innerHTML ?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Wave</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="editor.php">Edit this page >></a>
<span>Some text</span>
</body>
</html>` This is a shortened version of my code. I want to select from  </head> to </body>.

Comment: @Michael edit your question.

Comment: @Michael, Do you need comment nodes in HTML as place holders? in this case searching the DOM for comment nodes would be a bit costly operation if your HTML page is large